# A better way to get this result table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data table that has dates as rows and some product codes as columns that have sales volume on those dates. Product codes are repeated for different corresponding dates in the columns. I want to stack them together, so I need dates as rows and unique product codes as columns with the sums on that particular date. I got the resulting table by first unpivoting columns. At this step excel added numbers to the column names to distinguish them such as ab/ab2, bc/bc3, etc. Then I had to remove the numbers manually. I then used a pivot table. Is there a more practical way to accomplish this? The actual data I have is much bigger than this and it will be prone to errors while removing those numbers. I attached two screenshots, one for what actual data looks like, and the second is what I need as a result.
Thanks.

[image: original data][image: the format I need]

Comment: How did you do the unpivoting? Are you using PowerQuery for that? If so, please add to the post the text from the advanced editor for your current query and also add an image of the query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data appear like screenshot 1, then you could use a SUMPRODUCT formula to achieve your desired output. It requires a little formatting upfront:

First copy and paste your dates into another sheet. Second, get your DISTINCT product types as column headers in that sheet.

Then your cell M2 formula could look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$I$11)*($A$2:$A$11=$L2)*($B$1:$I$1=M$1))
```

The * symbol basically makes this "AND" logic. Using sumproduct in this manner is like using a SUMIFS formula, but you cannot use SUMIFS here due to multiple columns.

In the screenshot below, columns A:I represent your data, and columns L:Q represent how it could appear in another sheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!